# How to flatten data in python to load into sql db

Tags: python, sqlite

I have data in python that looks like the following (there are sometimes many entries of these long strings) I want to load it into a single database table with three fields:

```
2 63668772 Human_STR_738862 AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2 63675572 Human_STR_738864 ACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
```

...

I want it to look like this to import into sqlite3

```
2 63668772 Human_STR_738862 AAAAAAAAAAAA
2 63675572 Human_STR_738864 ACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
2 63668772 Human_STR_738862 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2 63675572 Human_STR_738864 ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
```

Comment: That is not Python code. Please show the actual data structure.

Comment: If I had python code I would be done.. What python code would trans from the data from one format to the other. My goal is to insert this into a sqlite table as a point of reference. The strings can vary from 1 to n on each record. So in the end there will be n records for each original row one for each string.

Comment: I doubt that all the stuff is part of single, large string (as shown). I want to know the Python data structure you're using.

Comment: They are data from VCFReader in pyvcf they are the Chromn,pos,id and alt columns where alt can vary..

Answer (score 0):

started working with scikit-allel. This allowed me to read the vcf directly into a dataframe(df) where I could specify the number # of ALTs. I melted the df by the keys I wanted and now can load the data directly from the df into sqlite.